# Why such an $x_{k+1}$ is of that form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Let $p=2$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ (notice that in particular $a$ is odd). Then for all $k\ge 1$ there exists at least one solution to the following equation : $x^2 \equiv a \pmod {2^k}$.

Here is the solution proposed :

Induction on $k$ :

$\bullet$ initialization : for $k=1$ (and even for $k=2, \ 3$) we have that : $1^2 \equiv a \pmod 2$ (mainly because $a = 1 +8l, \ l \in \mathbb{Z}$).

$\bullet$ step case : suppose that for a fixed $k \ (\ge 3$ w.l.o.g), hence there exists $x_k$ solution of the following equation : $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^k}$. Let us show that there exists a solution $x_{k+1}$ for the equation : $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^{k+1}}$.
Now the author use the trick that he wants to build such an $x_{k+1}$ of the form $x_{k+1} = x_k + 2^{k-1}\alpha$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ is to determine.

Finally it leads to $x_{k+1}^2 \equiv x_k^2 +2^k\alpha \equiv a + 2^k (s + \alpha) \pmod{2^{k+1}}$ with $s \in \{-1,0,1\}$. Depending on $s$, it gives $\alpha=\pm 1$ or $\alpha = 0$ and we have such the required $x_{k+1}.$

But my question is : **where does the idea of searching for an $x_{k+1}$ of this form come from ?**

In the case of $p>2$, $a$ a non-zero quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $k\ge 1$, I can see why we want to search $x_{k+1}$ of the form $x_{k} +p^k \beta$, $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$ to determine. Indeed the following homomorphism : $(\mathbb{Z}/p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$ is surjective as $p^{k} \mid p^{k+1}$ and so for $x_k \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$ its pre-image is of the form $x_k + p^k \beta \in (\mathbb{Z}/p^{k+1}\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$, with $\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$.

However for $p=2$, we cannot use the same method because depending on the value of $k$ the sub-groups are not necessary cyclic. But if you suppose $k\ge 3$, in that case you have a surjective homomorphism : $(\mathbb{Z}/2^{k+1}\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$ and for $x_k \in (\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$ its pre-image is of the form $x_k + 2^k \alpha \in (\mathbb{Z}/2^{k+1}\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$,  $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$. But taking the square of this, you lose the $\alpha$ you want to determine so you cannot conclude as in the previous case. Even if you suppose $k\ge 4$ and consider the surjective map : $(\mathbb{Z}/2^{k+1}\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2^{k-1}\mathbb {Z})^{\times}$ it does not work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Where does that trick come from?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a particular case of [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) (if there is a solution mod $p$, then there is a solution modulo $p^n, n\ge 2,$ under some assumption). The proof is also a particular case of a standard proof of that lemma.